# Boto S3 response Error : Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to upload large file to my bucket using parallel uploads. I came across the code from [here](http://www.topfstedt.de/python-parallel-s3-multipart-upload-with-retries.html) and decided to use it as it is very simple and easy to understand. However running the program gives me an error of

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>BF24672A4459F15E</RequestId><HostId>SN94E8Sg3QeiNQdOoB0CNZmAKZkVSrae8ORBOcjN9mKl07LjYV8hHhNG5Ox2f2bC</HostId></Error>
```

I went through all the different solution given here on stackoverflow and none of them were found to be the problem. I have complete access to the bucket and I can read, write, delete files from the bucket serially and only get this error when using this code. `s3cmd` also works fine and shows no error. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Code and stack trace pasted below:

code:

```
import math
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool #using dummy for debugging
import os

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from filechunkio import FileChunkIO
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser, NoOptionError

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read( 'tm/aws.cfg' )

#conn = S3Connection( config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_access_key_id' ), config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_secret_access_key' ) )
acs_key = config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_access_key_id' )
sec_key = config.get( 'prodAws', 'aws_secret_access_key' )
try:
    default_bucket = config.get( 'prodAws', 'bucket' )
except NoOptionError, e:
    print( "Configuration error({0})".format( e.message ) )
    exit()

def _upload_part(bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, multipart_id, part_num,
                 keyname, offset, bytes, amount_of_retries = 5):
    """
    Uploads a part with retries.
    """
    def _upload(retries_left=amount_of_retries):
        try:
            print( 'Start uploading part #%d ...' % part_num )
            conn = S3Connection( aws_key, aws_secret )
            bucket = conn.get_bucket( bucketname, validate=False )
            for mp in bucket.get_all_multipart_uploads():
                if mp.id == multipart_id:
                    with FileChunkIO( keyname, 'r', offset=offset, bytes=bytes) as fp:
                        mp.upload_part_from_file( fp=fp, part_num=part_num )
                    break
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            if retries_left:
                _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
            else:
                print( 'Failed uploading part #%d' % part_num )
                raise e
        else:
            print( 'Uploaded part #%d' % part_num )

    _upload()


def upload(bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, keyname, parallel_processes=5):
    """
    Parallel multipart upload.
    """
    conn = S3Connection( aws_key, aws_secret )
    bucket = conn.get_bucket( bucketname, validate=False )

    mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload( keyname )

    source_size = os.stat( keyname ).st_size
    bytes_per_chunk = max( int( math.sqrt( 5242880 ) * math.sqrt( source_size ) ), 5242880 )
    chunk_amount = int( math.ceil( source_size / float( bytes_per_chunk ) ) )

    pool = Pool( processes=parallel_processes )
    for i in range( chunk_amount ):
        offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
        remaining_bytes = source_size - offset
        bytes = min([ bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes ])
        part_num = i + 1
        #_upload_part(bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, mp.id, part_num, 
                #keyname, offset, bytes)
        pool.apply_async(_upload_part, [bucketname, aws_key, aws_secret, mp.id,
                                        part_num, keyname, offset, bytes] )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    if len( mp.get_all_parts() ) == chunk_amount:
        mp.complete_upload()
        key = bucket.get_key( keyname )
    else:
        mp.cancel_upload()

upload(default_bucket, acs_key, sec_key, 'bigfile.txt')
```

Stacktrace:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 113, in worker
  result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 46, in _upload_part
  _upload()
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 39, in _upload
  _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 39, in _upload
  _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 39, in _upload
  _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 39, in _upload
  _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 39, in _upload
  _upload( retries_left = retries_left - 1 )
￼ File "/home/desktop/s3/parup.py", line 42, in _upload
  raise e
```

Comment: The code appears to be pulling credentials from a file named `tm/aws.cfg` -- have you placed your credentials there? Alternatively, if you are running your code from an EC2 instance that has been assigned a role, or from a computer that can use the AWS CLI, then just use `S3Connection()` rather than passing credentials to the API call. It will find the credentials you've been using with `s3cmd` (presumably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue:

The issue was with the `for mp in bucket.get_all_multipart_uploads()`. i removed it and changed `if mp.id == multipart.id` to `if multipart.id`